# How to convert Firebase Map to Dart Map?

Tags: firebase, dictionary, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

This fails silently in Dart:

```
Map<String,String> dartMap = doc.data['keyForFieldthatContainsMap'];
```

doc is a firebase document (type DocumentSnapshot) that has a field "keyForFieldthatContainsMap" which contains a Map.

doc.data is of type:

```
Map<String,dynamic>
```

At runtime doc.data['keyForFieldthatContainsMap'] has the type:

```
_InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic>
```

from which I don't know how to access the keys and values.

I'm using the package:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
```

I'm looking for a way to read map fields just like I can read string, number, boolean,... fields from firebase.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your dartMap to `Map<dynamic,dynamic>`. Your error might occour cause you cant now which types your Map in Firestore has.

Comment: That works. The runtimetype of dartMap is still _InternalLinkedHashMap<dynamic, dynamic> but now I can use dart maps properties. Thank you very much!