# Contverting a firebase Map into a Dart Map

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart

Im trying to convert a firebase map i made into a map i can use in my dart app , but i keep getting the error : StreamProvider<List>, but no `catchError` was provided.

Exception:
An exception was throw by _MapStream<QuerySnapshot, List> listened by

StreamProvider<List>, but no `catchError` was provided.

Exception:
type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'Map<dynamic, dynamic>'

here is the place im trying to display my info its also giving me null but thats probably because of the map problem

```
final PendingOrders = Provider.of<List<Receipt>>(context);
    
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount: PendingOrders.length,
      itemBuilder: (builder,index){
        return Container(
          child: Text(PendingOrders[index].Status.toString()),
        );
      },
    );
```

this is where im trying to get my information from the firebase

```
List<Receipt> AllOrders(QuerySnapshot snapshot){
  return snapshot.docs.map((doc){
    return Receipt(
      id:doc.data()['ID'] ?? '',
      Status: doc.data()['Status'] ?? '',
      TotalPrice: doc.data()['TotalPrice'] ?? '',
      PaymentMethod: doc.data()['PaymentMethod'] ?? '',
      Date:doc.data()['Date'] ?? '',
      BoughtItems: doc.data()['Map'] ?? '',
    );
  }).toList();


}

Stream<List<Receipt>> get  PendingOrders{

  return availableOrders.where('Status',isEqualTo:"Pending").snapshots().map(AllOrders);
}
```

Here is the Receipt Model

```
class Receipt {
  String cashierName;
  String TotalPrice;
  String PaymentMethod;
  Timestamp Date;
  String Status;
  Map BoughtItems;
  String id;

  Receipt({this.id,this.cashierName,this.TotalPrice,this.PaymentMethod,this.Status,this.Date,this.BoughtItems});
  
}
```

[image: Here is a picture the shape of my firebase]
i have a map and the values inside it are double

Answer (score 0):

You could try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59892990/how-to-convert-firebase-map-to-dart-map):

> Try to change your `dartMap to Map<dynamic,dynamic>`.

Your error might occour because you can't now which types your Map in Firestore has.

Comment: the error is from itemCount:PendingOrders.length i think its walking through my pendingOrders as if its a map instead of a stream of lists